# How to obtain coefficients' p-values from a nested random effect model using lmeresampler

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, p-value

I estimated a mixed effect model with a nested random effect structure (participants were in different groups) with the `lmer` command of the `lme4`    package.
`mixed.model <- lmer(ln.v ~ treatment*level+age+income+(1 | group/participant),data=data)`
Then I bootstrapped the `bootstrap` command from the `lmeresampler` package because of the nested structure. I used the semi-parametric bootstrap.
`boot.mixed.model <- bootstrap(model = mixed.model, type = "cgr", fn = extractor, B = 10000, resample=c(data$group,data$participant))`
I can obtain bootsrapped confidence intervals via `boot.ci`    (package `boot`) but in addition I want to report the coefficients' p-values. The output of the bootstrapped model `boot.mixed.model` provides only the bias and the standard error:

```
Bootstrap Statistics :
         original        bias    std. error
t1*   0.658442415 -7.060056e-02  2.34685668
t2*  -0.452128438 -2.755208e-03  0.17041300
…
```

What is the best way to calculate the p-values based on these values?

Answer (score 0):

I am unaware of the package called `lmeresampler`, and it seems to have been removed from `cran` due to compatibility issues (failed cran checks).

Also, the question does not include data and `extractor` is not defined, so the example is not [reproducible.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) However the output is the same as you would get by using the `bootMer` function from `lme4` so produce and example using the inbuilt function.

Basically this follows the example from the `help(bootMer)` page, but expanded for the specific problem. If the object returend by the `lmeresampler` package is similar, it will contain the objects used.

## Reproducible example

```
library(lme4)
data(Dyestuff, package = "lme4")
fm01ML <- lmer(Yield ~ 1|Batch, Dyestuff, REML = FALSE)
```

Now the `bootMer` function simply requires a function, which outputs a vector of interesting parameters.

```
StatFun <- function(merMod){
    pars <- getME(merMod, c("fixef", "theta", "sigma"))
    c(beta = pars$fixef, theta = unname(pars$theta * pars$sigma), sigma = pars$sigma) ### <<== Error corrected
}
```

We can perform our bootstrapping by using the `bootMer`, which also contains parametric options in `type` (i suggest reading the details in the `help(bootMer)` page for more information)

```
boo01 <- bootMer(fm01ML, StatFun, nsim = 100, seed = 101)
```

Now for more precise p-values, I'd advice p-values greater closer to 1000 but for time reasons it might not be feasible in every circumstance.

Regardless the output is stored in a matrix `t`, which we can use to perform a simple Kolmogorov-supremum test:

```
H0 <- c(0, 0, 0)
Test <- sweep(abs(boo01$t), 2, H0, "-") <= H0 ###<<=== Error corrected
pVals <- colSums(Test)/nrow(Test)
print(pVals)
#output#
beta.(Intercept)            theta            sigma 
            0.00             0.12             0.00
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! ```extractor``` was just a function in order to obtain FE coefficients and SDs of the random effects. Unfortunately, I was not able to reproduce your example. Trying to run ```Test``` I get: ```Error in abs(boo01) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function```
I found an interesting article by BMJ (2011; doi: https://doi.org/10.1136/bmj.d2304), the authors illustrate the calculation of p-values from confidence intervals. They suggest this approach:
1) Standard error = (upper limit CI – lower limit CI)/(2×1.96);
2) z = Est/SE;
3) p = exp(−0.717×z − 0.416×z^2).

Comment: It sounds like you simply copy-pasted the code. `boo01` would be equivalent to `boot.mixed.model` if i understand your question correctly.

Comment: First I tested it with my data with the equivalent ```boot.mixed.model``` and then I tried to reproduce it with ```Dyestuff``` data and the code you provided but in both cases I cannot run ```Test``` because ```abs``` does not accept an ```boot.mixed.model```as input.

Comment: Ahh my bad. `boo01$t`

Comment: I've updated the reproducible example. In my haste i made 2 minor errors, which made it rather hard to reproduce. my bad.